# Why do I get a random number in the first element of the sorted array?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, bubble-sort

I am new to C and when I do this which makes the elements in the list arranged:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int list[] = {6, 4, 8, 1, 0, 9, 11, 50, 60, 10};
    int i, j, aux, k;
    int len = sizeof(list) / sizeof(list[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < len; j++)
        {
            if (list[j] > list[j + 1])
            {
                aux = list[j + 1];
                list[j + 1] = list[j];
                list[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    for (k = 0; k < len; k++)
    {
        printf("%d  ", list[k]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
-13168  0  1  4  6  8  9  10  11  50
```

Why is the first value `-13168`?

Comment: You are sorting while accessing beyond the array, so the strange value is something you read from outside the array.

Comment: how i am accessing beyond the array i start from 0 to the array length

Comment: Yes, and then you read from one ahead.

Comment: `if (list[j] > list[j+])` and `aux = list[j+1];`, etc. — these read outside the array as when `j` is `len - 1`, `j + 1` is `len` and `list[len]` is out of bounds.

Comment: `list[j + 1]` does not exist when `j == n - 1`

Comment: Note too that 60 is missing from your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said `list[j + 1]` steps out of the bounds of the array, and as said using `for (j = 0; j < len - 1; j++)` will solve the issue.

However, as it is, the second loop will always go through the entire array and that is not needed, as the values are swapped `i` will be incremented and the number of needded iterations will become lesser , so you can use `i` iterator in the stop condition of the second loop thus optimizing it by reducing the number of iterations.

```
for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) //len - 1 is enough
{
    for (j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++) //replacing < len with  < len - i - 1
    {
        if (list[j] > list[j + 1])
        {
            aux = list[j + 1];
            list[j + 1] = list[j];
            list[j] = aux;
        }
    }
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1Ux0lQLJQOyLbQGg)

This is a more appropriate bubble sort.

Even for such a small array the difference in performance is noticeable, but there is still room for improvement.

When a swap no longer occurs in the loop it means that the array is sorted,  so if we were to add a flag to stop ordering when this happens then you would have a very well optimized bubble sort algorithm:

```
int ordered = 0;
//...    
for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
{
    ordered = 0; //reset flag
    for (j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++)
    {
        if (list[j] > list[j + 1])
        {
            aux = list[j + 1];
            list[j + 1] = list[j];
            list[j] = aux;  
            ordered = 1; //if the swap occurs, the ordering continues
        }
    }
    if (ordered == 0) //otherwise the array is ordered and the ordering ends
        break; 
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iw0NjmGRFNGp4tXA)

As you can see by the testing this is a very fast bubble sort.

[Benchmark results:](https://www.quick-bench.com/q/aCycfF1b-3dMUN4CHYr6hiEXcKg)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both your `i` and your `j` walk all the range of legal indices in the array.
But you do access `list[j+1]` which is one beyond the array, read there and sort the value you get from there.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the second loop:

```
for(j = 0; j < len; j++)
```

should be

```
for(j = 0; j < len - 1; j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop is useless. You never use `i`. I think you wanted:

```
for(i=0;i<len;i++){
    for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        if(list[j] > list[i]){
            aux = list[i];
            list[i] = list[j];
            list[j] = aux;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorting requires to do the inner loop often enough to do all the needed bubbling....

Comment: The outer loop isn't useless — though it may be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

When you are accessing `list[j+1]`, you are out of bound in last iteration .

So, change `inner loop` to :

```
       for(j=0;j<len-1;j++){ }
```